# Trigonometric question combined with questions about Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

I'm new to Mathematica and I am struggling with the Syntax and the functions of this "programming" language.

I'm looking for a way to solve sin2 α cos3 α = tan4 α

But if I try to run it through the Solve[] function I recieve an error.

I'm not looking for hand holding and having someone give me the answer. What I am trying to do is to learn which functions work where and how I successfully can calculate questions like these in Mathematica.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe26)

Comment: You have to be careful of the syntax. Sin, Cos and Tan all have capital letters to start with, and also use square brackets i.e. Sin[2 alpha], etc... The other thing you have to be careful about is the use of the = sign. For solving equations you use the double == . Check in the help for Solve for examples and it should be fairly clear

Comment: One good place to look is the help page for `Solve`. Help > Wolfram Documentation > Solve will get you there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = Sin[2 a] Cos[3 a] == Tan[4 a];
```

The functions are periodic so there are many periodic solutions.

```
Solve[eqn, a] // Short[#, 4] &
```

[image]

Restrict the range of `a` to some region of interest

```
sol = Solve[{eqn, 0 <= a <= 2 Pi}, a]
```

[image]

The approximate numeric values are

```
sol // N

(* {{a -> 0.}, {a -> 1.5708}, {a -> 3.14159}, {a -> 4.71239}, {a -> 
   6.28319}, {a -> 5.60235}, {a -> 0.680831}, {a -> 4.11126}, {a -> 2.17193}} *)
```

Graphically,

```
Plot[Evaluate[List @@ eqn], {a, 0, 2 Pi},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[{a, eqn[[1]]} /. sol]}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you so very much Bob! This is way beyond what I was expecting. Again, thank you very very much!